# What are the Void Crosses and Dark Stars in Little Stars for Little Wars 2?

Tags: little-stars-for-little-wars-2.0

What are the void crosses? The dark stars? How do those relate to the "Black Hole Detected"?

Answer (score 1):

Like the 54 red crosses per part of a galaxy in normal mode you you can get the blue void crosses in hard mode. Just change the game mode in the status bar.

To obtain the black dark stars you have to find the hidden black holes. In Galaxy Reborn 3 of 9 are hidden in levels 2-11, 2-13 and 2-16.

Comment: I've also found them in: 4-6, 5-14, 7-7, and 8-18.